# angular 2 where I should apply standard web api like window.resize

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to know in which place of app I can apply standard web api calls (like window.onresize etc.  or api from thirdparty library.)  Work with DOM should be inside directive, but what I should do in that case?

I saw that somebody place the same stuff inside components and place it inside constructor or ngOnInit. But I don't sure that is correct.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. Update with code.
I don't sure if it correct to use that logic inside constructor. So where it can be used in right way? Thanks
Here is sample:

```
 constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams,
              private _ngZone:NgZone,
              private _el:ElementRef) {

          window.onresize = (e) => {
            this.getScreenWidth();
          };                
         }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getScreenWidth();
  }


private ordersEntityQuantity:number;
  private getScreenWidth() {
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
      this.width = window.innerWidth;
    });
    switch(true) {
      case this.width < 1100 : this.ordersEntityQuantity = 1;
        break;
      case this.width < 1300 : this.ordersEntityQuantity = 2;
        break;
      case this.width < 1500 : this.ordersEntityQuantity = 3;
        break;
      case this.width >= 1500 : this.ordersEntityQuantity = 5;
    }
    this.lastOrdersEntity = this.firstOrdersEntity + this.ordersEntityQuantity;
  }
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Your question doesn't make any sense without exact description about what you try to accomplish. Depending on what exactly you try to do a different place is the right one for the code.

Comment: May be what you need is responsive design that automatically adjusts to the screen.

Comment: No. I want to know where I can place that code in best practice. Should I leave it inside component or move to some directive etc. ?

Comment: the code above it's just example (I know that it is bad :) ) but I want to know where I should place code with the same logic?